# React - Using svg <defs> with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am trying to use `svg` with `<defs>` defined elsewhere in the page.

```js
const data =  {
  icons: {
    freezable: "<svg><path d=""/></svg>",
     vegetarian: "<svg><path d=""/></svg>",
  }
};

const SvgDefs = (icons) => {
  return Object.keys(icons).map(iconName => {
    return <span key={data.icons[iconName]} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: data.icons[iconName].replace('svg', `svg id="svg-${iconName}"`)
    }} />;
  });
};
```

With my component rendering this as:

```
 return <svg aria-hidden="true" id="svgdefs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
      <SvgDefs icons={data.icons} />
    </defs>
 </svg>
```

However, when I check the Elements tab in Chrome Dev Tools, I see that the spans containing the svgs are outside of the `<defs>` block:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you checking ` icons`? By definition a functional component is called with props, even if it's an empty object it's always truthy.

Comment: Don't lose sight of the question.

Comment: Also don't forget where you're asking questions. Comments are comments, not answers: answers are there to give you the solution to your problem (or, at the very least, useful information), comments are for everything, including asking about your general approach.

Comment: also note that you're passing `icons` into your functional component, but then you reference `data.icons` inside your function even though `data` should definitely not be accessible to your component. Calling  your functional component argument `props` is always a good idea here: it forces you into making sure your scoping is safe.

Comment: It's a contrived example, but thank you for taking the time to point this out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from you calling your functional component's input argument `icons`, and the assumptions that stem from that naming choice.

Functional components are passed JSX properties wrapped up in an object, conventionally called `props`, so call your function input `props` and then get your data back out from that. Since you passed `icons=...`, you'll need access that data through `props.icons`:

```
const SvgDefs = (props) => {
  const { icons } = props;
  return Object.entries(icons).map(([name, html]) => {
    return <span key={name} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: html.replace('svg', `svg id="svg-${name}"`)
    }} />;
  });
};
```

Although it would make a lot more sense to not have SVG strings in your data.icons to begin with: just have more JSX so you don't need to dangerously set innerHTML at all.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why the <span> tags are appearing outside the <defs> tag.

Comment: That doesn't make it a downvote: remember that answer posts are also for "things that are useful in helping, but aren't the full answer, and don't fit in a comment". Taking this post's message to heart and redoing your own code, we get https://replit.com/@Pomax/70586430, which works perfectly fine. with the spans inside the `<defs>` element.

Comment: How is it that your example on replit works (the spans are in the <defs> block, but mine does not?)

Comment: Hard to say without the rest of the code around it that shows what else might be getting rendered in... the code that you have in your post can't really place any span at all, as it should throw a runtime error the moment it hits `data.icons[iconName].replace`  (since there is no `data.icons.icons`, and so that `replace()` should throw a "cannot call X of undefined" error). You may need to update the post to a true [mcve] if we want to get to the real bottom of things =/

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the reason was because `<span>` cannot be used inside `<defs>`. I used `<symbol>` instead and all worked as expected.

Comment: BTW: the `<symbol>` element doesn't need to be nested within a def, since it's invisible by default. Actually, you would completely strip the spans and change your nested svgs element type to `<symbol>` (symbols also support a custom viewBox)